# Surface integral with domain that contains an infinite cone

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I'm stuck on the following question:

> Find $\iint\limits_S {ydS}$ where $S$ is the part of the plane $z=1+y$ that lies inside the cone $z = \sqrt {2({x^2} + {y^2})} $

I tried to parametrize $x,y$ as following:

$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  x = u \hfill \\
  y = v \hfill \\
  z = 1 + v \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \Rightarrow dS = \sqrt 2 dudv$$

So, the double integral turns out to be:

$$\iint\limits_D {v\sqrt 2 dudv}$$
It seems to be right, but there does not seem to be any way to set up the proper boundaries for the domain $D$. I experimented with a polar substitution, but unfortunately, since the domain is an infinite cone, I am unable to quantify it.

The answer should be $2\pi$. Does anyone know a good strategy to solve problems with these kinds of domains?

Comment: Your region of integration is the _intersection_ of a (solid) cone with a plane, and since the "maximum slope" of the plane is $1$ while the cone generators have slope $\sqrt{2} > 1$, the intersection is an ellipse. A sketch will probably help, but to describe the boundary of the ellipse algebraically, set $1 + y = \sqrt{2(x^{2} + y^{2})}$ to get the projection into the $(x, y)$-plane. :)